# Will javascript embedded in a pdf with adobe run in preview on a mac?

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, adobe

I want to create a fillable pdf form that runs script to check if fields are filled out correctly. I know that I can do something like this using adobe, but will an interactive pdf created using adobe run on preview/ another pdf viewer if the user that downloads it doesn't have adobe?

What is the best way to make a fillable pdf with code embedded that checks if fields are filled out correctly? Should I just make an html page instead?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just try it? That shouldn't cause any harm.

Comment: Just make an HTML page. You can't control what application or browser opens the PDF and they all have different (or no) JavaScript capabilities. If you need a PDF out the back end, there are tools to capture the data from the HTML and populate the form.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @M.Kay please let us know what path you took. I am in a similar situation. I've tried and looks like PDF javascript (made by adobe acrobat) does not run on mac preview application. I just wanted to make sure that it is indeed the case.